# Return only certain columns / fields from Dapper connection.Query<T>(sql)

Tags: c#, web-services, serialization, dapper

### The problem and the question

*Problem:* I thought that `connection.Query<myT>("Select A, C from myTable");` would only fill the selected columns and the matching fields of the underlying class / object. But it seems that this is not the case - (although the reason might be my misuse or how i serialize the result). Currently all fields of the underlying class are in serialized result.

*Questions:* What can i do to return only certain properties based on the select and serialize them?

### The setup

Based on **[A look at dapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212274/A-Look-at-Dapper-NET)** i put the following together:

#### A simple class for the entity / model:

```
public sealed class Category 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
}
```

#### IDbConnection and Dapper Repository Class

Return an open `IDbConnection`

```
protected static IDbConnection OpenConnection()
{
    IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}
```

use the above connection with dapper in the repository class

```
public IEnumerable<Category> GetCategories()
{
    using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection())
    {
        const string sql = " SELECT Id, A, C FROM Categories";
        return connection.Query<Category>(sql);
    }
}
```

#### Serialze the result and send it to client by Asmx

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetCategoriesTreelist()
{
    var repo = new CategoryRepository();
    IEnumerable<Category> categories = repo.GetCategories();            
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(categories);
}
```

#### Output

Currently every field is serialized instead of only the selected fields from the sql statement above.

- What can i do to retrun only a few fields?
- Is the reason that every field is serialized based on dapper or on `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()` or based on my misunderstanding  / misuse?

Thanks

### Update after Marc answered the question

Missing the forest for the trees: Like Marc said Dapper has no part that the serialization returns all members of the objects. This simple test shows that all members of the underlying class are serialized.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetCategoriesTestObjectSerialization()
{
    
    List<Category> categoriesList =  new List<Category>(){
        new Category(){Id=1, A="a1", C="foo"},
        new Category(){Id=2, A="a2", C="bar"},
        new Category(){Id=3, A="a3", C="baz"}
    };
    IEnumerable<Category> categories= from c in categoriesList 
                                                where c.Id > 0
                                                select c;
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(categories);
}
```

Creating a simple [Data Transfer Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649585.aspx) solves the issue: `IEnumerable<CategoryDTO> categories= from c in categoriesList where c.Id > 0 select c;`

```
private class CategoryDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string A{ get; set; }
    public string C{ get; set; }
}
```

[More on DTOs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fundamentally a serializer factor. Dapper explicitly never assigns to anything that it doesn't get at a column. However, I suspect that if you serialize a `new Category()` you'll see very similar behaviour. Options:

- live with it
- create a DTO model that fits what you want, and query into that instead
- investigate whether the serializer supports conditional serialization (but note this can require a lot of boilerplate)